# Having trouble with stored procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I was wondering where I'm going wrong with creating this stored procedure using XAMPP.

```
use PizzaShop;

delimiter /

CREATE PROCEDURE `updateDelivery` (IN @driver INT(3), IN @orderNum INT(5))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `orders`(`deliveredBy`,`complete`) VALUES(@driver ,TRUE) WHERE orders.Order_No = @orderNum;
end;
/

delimiter ;
```

The error I'm getting is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@driver INT(3), IN @orderNum INT(5)) BEGIN INSERT INTO
>   `order`(`deliveredBy`,`' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax with an insert statement with a where clause is invalid and doesn't make much sense. The presence of a where clause suggests that maybe what you want to do is an update?

```
use PizzaShop;

delimiter /

CREATE PROCEDURE `updateDelivery` (IN driver INT(3), IN orderNum INT(5))
BEGIN
  UPDATE orders
  SET deliveredBy = driver, completed = TRUE
  WHERE orders.Order_No = orderNum;
END /

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Sorry, I had already corrected that. Same error after the correction :(

Comment: Working fine now. Well spotted :P

Answer (score 0):

Input parameter names need to be local variables to the SP, but not with session variable identifier syntax.

**Change**:

```
(IN @driver INT(3), IN @orderNum INT(5))
```

**To**:

```
(IN driver INT(3), IN orderNum INT(5))
```

**The `insert` statement in SP body would be**:

```
INSERT INTO `orders`(`deliveredBy`,`complete`)
VALUES (driver ,TRUE) WHERE orders.Order_No = orderNum;
```

Comment: `insert ... where` isn't a valid construct.

Comment: yes, it should be an `update` ... I was only concentrating on the initial syntax error ... :)